# How to identify subelements from SVG in android?

Tags: android, svg, androidsvg

I'm using [SVG rendering library for Android](https://bigbadaboom.github.io/androidsvg/) create a drawable vector by parsing SVG. Then I want to identify elements of it and make them fillable.

For example I want to identify all six elements separately in the SVG file as follows and I want to make them fillable.

[image]

What is the appropriate way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AndroidSVG is currently render-only.  So you can't modify the SVG or recolour any part of it and re-render.

I see two solutions:

1. Load your SVG in as a string.  Then recolour your image by modifying the SVG using string manipulations, then pass it to AndroidSVG via an InputStream.
2. Have a stack of seven SVGs. One for each petal colour and the flower outline on top.  Then make each petal visible as the right area is clicked on.